# Can not click on Paginator Button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, pagination, richfaces

I am using JSF and Richface version 4.3.7 and try to make a paginator But They are unclickable :(  I used  So the first and last value are visible but they are unclickable. First I use a4j:keepAlive But seems like it is not valid in richface4 I am new in jsf so thanx if u help me Where I am doing it wrong?

[image]

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    </style>
        <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columnClasses="acent">
        <rich:dataScroller id="sc2" for="List" reRender="sc1" maxPages="7" page="#{RichLazyDataModelImpl.getCurrentPage()}">
        <f:facet name="first">
                        <h:outputText value= "first" styleClass="scrollerCell"/>
              </f:facet>
              <f:facet name="last">
                        <h:outputText value="Last" styleClass="scrollerCell"/>
              </f:facet>
    </rich:dataScroller>

            <rich:dataTable width="483" id="List" columnClasses="col"
                value="#{RichLazyDataModelImpl.getDataList()}" var="category">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <rich:columnGroup>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Mobile" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="message" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Status" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="time" />
                        </h:column>
                    </rich:columnGroup>
                </f:facet>

                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{category.getMsg_mobile()}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{category.getMessage()}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{category.getDirection()}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{category.getMsg_time()}" />
                </h:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
           </h:panelGrid> 
        </h:form>

    </ui:composition>
```

Comment: Your resources are not being loaded, are you using `<h:head>`?

Comment: Thanx @Makhiel No This the whole code not using <h:head>

Answer (score 2):

Try Using your pagination in footer like this

```
    <f:facet name="footer">
<rich:dataScroller render="List">
</rich:dataScroller>
</f:facet>
```